# Splitting up a variable in bash

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, mp3

I have a bunch of songs that I have downloaded that I am trying to convert to *.mp3* and rename. After converting the *.m4a* file to *mp3* with `ffmpeg`, they are all in the format of Artist Name - Song Name.mp3. I want to be able to separate the Song name and Artist name into their own variables, so I can rename the file and tag the songs with the song name and artist name.

So, How can I separate a variable into two variables, each respectively containing the artist name and song name, where the two pieces of information is separated by a ' - ' in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using shell

```
v='Artist Name - Song Name.mp3'
v=${v%.mp3}
song=${v#* - }
artist=${v% - $song}
echo a=$artist, s=$song
```

This produces the output:

```
a=Artist Name, s=Song Name
```

Notice that this approach, like the sed solution below, consistently divides the artist and song at the *first* occurrence of `-`.  Thus, if the name is:

```
v='Artist Name - Song Name - 2nd Take.mp3'
```

Then, the output is:

```
a=Artist Name, s=Song Name - 2nd Take
```

This approach is POSIX and works under `dash` and `busybox` as well as under `bash`.

### Using sed

```
$ v='Artist Name - Song Name.mp3'
$ { read -r artist; read -r song; } < <(sed 's/.mp3$//; s/ - /\n/' <<<"$v")
$ echo a=$artist s=$song
a=Artist Name s=Song Name
```

This assumes (1) the first occurrence of `-` divides the artist name from the song name, and (2) the file name, `$v`, has only line (no newline characters).

We can overcome the second limitation by using, if your tools support it,  NUL as the separator instead of newline:

```
$ { read -r -d $'\0' artist; read -r -d $'\0' song; } < <(sed 's/.mp3$//; s/ - /\x00/' <<<"$v"); echo a=$artist s=$song
a=Artist Name s=Song Name
```

Here is an example with newline characters inside both the artist and song names:

```
$ v=$'Artist\nName - Song\nName.mp3'
$ { read -r -d $'\0' artist; read -r -d $'\0' song; } < <(sed 's/.mp3$//; s/ - /\x00/' <<<"$v"); echo "a=$artist"; echo "s=$song"
a=Artist
Name
s=Song
Name
```

#### How it works

The sed command removes the `.mp3` suffix and then replaces `-` with a newline character:

```
sed 's/.mp3$//; s/ - /\n/' <<<"$v"
```

The output of the sed command consists of two lines.  The first line has the artist name and the second the song name.  These are then read by the two `read` commands.

Comment: Since bash strings cannot contain nulls, there is no difference between `-d $'\0'` and `-d ''` , except that the second one is easier to type.

Comment: This will be inefficient if you call `sed` once for each of a large number of files.

Comment: @chepner There seem to be many ways to an end.  I added a pure shell solution.

Comment: Yeah, it all depends on the context. `sed` is good if you have lots of file names to process at once, say a file with one filename per line.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="Artist Name - Song Name.mp3"
songname="${name#*- }"
songnamewithoutextentions="${songname%.*}"
artistname="${name% -*}"
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$artistname" "$songname" "$songnamewithoutextentions"
```

Output:

```
Artist: Artist Name
Song: Song Name.mp3
Song name without extention: Song Name
```

Explanation:

`"${name#*- }"` is the string after the first match of `-` in `$name`

`"${name% -*}"` is the string before the last match (first match from right) of `-` in `$name`

You can know more about Bash parameter expansion from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression matching built into `bash`:

```
regex='(.*) - (.*).mp3'
[[ $v =~ $regex ]]
artist=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
song=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Comment: Nice demonstration of an advanced bash feature: +1